# get_where with md5()

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I want to perform this simple query using `Codeigniter`:

```
$user = $this->db->get_where($type,array("id"=>$id));
```

`$type` is the name of the table and
`$id` is a `md5()` value so I want to do something like `$this->db->get_where($type,array(md5("id")=>$id));` that of course is not possible to do.

the answer could be `$this->db->query('select * from $type where MD5(id) = $id');` but I would prefer a more compact way like `get_where()` to perform query.

any suggestions?

Comment: want to do $this->db->get_where($type,array("md5(id)",$id)); but it doesn't work.

Comment: your $id is single string or more than one string

Comment: then send just an $id why you are using array("id"=>$id)

Comment: see get_where function http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Comment: I don't want to load all the table and loop all the records if md5($record->id)==$passed_id

Comment: yeah i got it. Whats the error you are getting.

Comment: dear Venkat, another mistake I made!!! what I wrote works perfectly! I wrote $this->db->get_where($type,array(md5("id")=>$id)); but the answer is $this->db->get_where($type,array("md5(id)"=>$id)); I actually get the record I am looking for!!! thanks anyway

Comment: no problem dude.......any time if u need help post it we will help

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->where('MD5(id)', $id, FALSE);
```

The 3rd argument when set to FALSE will stop CI from protecting your field and table names with backticks so instead of turning the code into:

```
WHERE `MD5(id)` = 'THE ID'
```

it will be:

```
WHERE MD5(id) = 'THE ID'
```

Comment: He don't want to use where clause separately. He like to use get_where or getwhere function...........

Comment: hey cryptic may i chat with u some time. I need some info from you

Comment: @Venkat sure. Make room and invite, gotta be quick have to head to bed 6am here O.o

Answer (score 0):

`$this->db->get_where($type,array("md5(id)"=>$id));` works perfectly. I get the record I want.

Comment: I wander why you are using MD5 on tables column name.

Comment: So MySQL will get the MD5 of the that value for row so to then check it against $id.

Comment: it's not in the table column name, but in the column value of the column named id. md5() is also a mysql function...

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question which I came across recently and found this as the top result in Google.

```
$user = $this->db->get_where( $type, array( 'md5( id ) =' => $id ) );
```

You can also substitute = for other operators such as LIKE and NOT LIKE.